# SQLAlchemy - Relationship with filtering based on subsquery

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Given two tables:

```
class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'A'
    a_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class AInfo(Base)
    a_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(A.a_id), primary_key=True)
    version = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    info = Column(String)
```

I'd like to create a relationship from `A` to the latest version of `AInfo` (highest `version` number). It can be view only.

Is there any way to do this? Is there a way to put a subquery in a relationship?

Note: I can't simply put version on A because in practice I have multiple tables with different version numbers, and I just want the latest version of each.

Currently I'm using a property with a subquery instead of a relationship.

Thanks!

Comment: What's the advantage of a relationship over a property for something so specific? I guess it allows eager loading? Can you show us the code for your property?